# Unable build the angular 2 project using ng build --prod

Tags: angular, angular-material, firebase-hosting

I have created a angular 2 project using angular material. I am trying to host my project using firebase deployment process.

My application is successfully running on my server.But when I am trying to build my application its giving me the following error as shown below in the image.

---

[image]

please help me to resolve this

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: which file should I show.?

Comment: which code has error :D

Comment: i just edited my question i pasted the code for form.d.ts

Comment: can you please check\

Comment: Which operating system are you using ?

Comment: but its saying /* generated bundle do not edit */

Comment: I am working on windows R2 standard

Comment: 64 bit Operating System

Comment: can i use ng build --prod --aot command?

Comment: Hi, Are you using `let-variablename` in your html side?

Comment: means i didnt understand

Comment: i have used let keyword within my mat-table component

Comment: I have update my answer.

Comment: hello.... can you please check this question on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681691/implementing-filter-for-table-in-angular-2-based-on-entered-values

Comment: hello ,.... can you please help me with this question...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48804782/unable-to-filter-the-data-in-the-matselect-accessed-using-the-http-get-in-angu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:  for `let- is only support for ng-template` error.

You have use `let-variablename` some where in you html side.  The error says you can't use it anywhere instead of ng-template.

### Solution 1.

Use `ng-template` wherever you are using `NgForOf`

like below this,

if you are using this kind of below code.

```
 <div ngFor let-variableName [ngForOf]="ListOfData" let-index=index ></div>
```

Then it should be change it into `ng-template`

```
 <ng-template ngFor let-variableName [ngForOf]="ListOfData" let-index=index ></ng-template>
```

### Solution 2

Use this below for loop

```
*ngFor="let variableName of ListOfData; let index = index"
```

instead of which is you are using kind

```
ngFor let-variableName [ngForOf]="ListOfData" let-i=index
```

I hope this  above both  solutions are helps you.

### Edit:

Run with this below command instead of yours

```
 ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false
```

Comment: is there any way to skip this?

Comment: Why you can't resolve this? wherever you used `ngFor let-variableName [ngForOf]="ListOfData"` this line please change to `*ngFor="let variableName of ListOfData; let index = index"`

Comment: i didnt use this syntax in my app\

Comment: i used  <mat-option *ngFor="let Building of buildings  | filter:filtertext " [value]="Building.value">   {{ Building.viewValue }}   </mat-option>

Comment: @you may use this. unless this error not come. Please check one more time. try to find this word `ngForOf`

Comment: i didnot use NgForOf any where

Comment: @Heena okay just find this word in your whole project like `let-`

Comment: i searched my whole project i didnt find ngForOf used any where in my app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164329/discussion-between-heena-and-ramesh-rajendran).

Comment: hello ,, can you please go to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48620517/applying-pagination-and-select-boxes-for-grid-in-angular-material-for-angular-2

Comment: hi... can you please checkout this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642039/http-get-request-in-angular-2-to-fetch-data-from-a-json-file-placed-in-assets

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have included angular form in your app module and imported it properly

`import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';`

Again if it doesn't work , then trying removing --aot --prod build .
Aot optimizes your build , so probably any of your unused code might be causing build problem

Comment: just try using `ng build`

Comment: yes i just imported the above module correctly ... now its resolved.. thanks a lot

Comment: i have edited my question with the new error i am facing ..can you please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560233/unable-build-the-angular-2-project-using-ng-build-prod?noredirect=1#comment84117351_48560233

Comment: please can you check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560233/unable-build-the-angular-2-project-using-ng-build-prod .. and help me to resolve this new error