# Applying pagination and select boxes for grid in angular material for angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to implement grid form angular material in my angular application to display data related to my application.

I have implemented the table for displaying the data received from the database from a Rest micro service.

Below shown is my table for which I have implemented the select checkboxes and paginator.

### .html file of the table

```
    <mat-card>
            <mat-card-content>
            <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
                  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

                <!-- Checkbox Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                    <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                                  [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                                  [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
                    </mat-checkbox>
                  </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                    <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                                  (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                                  [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
                    </mat-checkbox>
                  </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Position Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Name Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="AlertDate">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Alert Date </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.AlertDate}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Weight Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="subject">
                  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Subject </mat-header-cell>
                  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.subject}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>


                <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
                         (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
                </mat-row>
              </mat-table>
            </div>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

But I want to implement grid instead of table. Can we apply same select checkboxes functionality and pagination for the grid list even?

If possible can anybody please guide me how can we do this ?

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: im having another question... can you please tell me how can i access json data saved in assets folder in my browser?

Comment: i created a file details.json in assets folder.. i just want to see the data in browser so  went to url localhost:4200/assets/details.json

Comment: but in browser im not seeing my json data..... is my url wrong?

Comment: Are you sure! Your folder have that file?

Comment: yes i am having accountdetails.json file in assets folder with this data[
 {"acc-id":1, "acc-des":"aaa", "investigator":"a-inves", "department":"adept", 
 "dept-id":"101", "deptdesc":"adesc", "CPC":"OR" , "location":"aloc"},

 {"acc-id":2, "acc-des":"aaa", "investigator":"a-inves", "department":"adept", 
 "dept-id":"101", "deptdesc":"adesc", "CPC":"OR" , "location":"aloc"},
];

Comment: [ {"acc-id":1, "acc-des":"aaa", "investigator":"a-inves", "department":"adept", "dept-id":"101", "deptdesc":"adesc", "CPC":"OR" , "location":"aloc"}, {"acc-id":2, "acc-des":"aaa", "investigator":"a-inves", "department":"adept", "dept-id":"101", "deptdesc":"adesc", "CPC":"OR" , "location":"aloc"} ]; –

Comment: i corrected my json file throungh validate json ,,even then my json file is not displayed on browser

Comment: its giving me message in my console "Message received from background .Values reset

Comment: i got my json data in browser.

Comment: Add your solution into the answer.

Comment: hello...please check this link if you can and help me ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48657932/how-to-implement-get-service-to-fetch-data-into-my-mat-table-in-angular-2?noredirect=1#comment84313542_48657932

Comment: I am accessing account details from a backend service and just accessing department values in my department dropdown ....can you please tell me how can i access distinct data in my dropdown as my dropdown contains duplicates....?

Comment: hi.. can you please check out this link ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769015/filter-in-the-dropdown-not-working-with-data-from-http-get-request

Comment: hello Ramesh Sir.... can you please checkout this link....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49007738/how-to-sum-up-the-values-entered-in-the-mat-table-column-using-mat-input-in-angu