# How to implement get service to fetch data into my mat-table in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material, http-get

I have created a dropdown with name **department** using the **mat-selec**t and applied filter for the dropdown.

I created a service with name **accountdetail** from which i can fetch data from a json file into the department dropdown.

I have implemented the table using angular materials **mat-table** component and i want fetch data from the same service in to my table.

### Below shown is my accountdetail.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {RouterModule, Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AccountdetailService {

  constructor(private http:Http ) { }

  accountdetails()
  {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/assets/accountdetails.json')
    .map(result => result.json());
  }}
```

### account.component.ts

```
import {Component, ViewChild, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

import {MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';

import { AccountdetailService } from '../accountdetail.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  templateUrl: './account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account.component.scss']

})


export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {

 filtertext:string;
 departments : any;


constructor( private accdetailservice: AccountdetailService ) { }

ngOnInit(){
  this.accdetailservice.accountdetails()
  .subscribe(data => this.departments = data);


  //.subscribe(data => {console.log(data)})
}



  /* Table Starts here
  ---------------------- */
 displayedColumns1 = ['accno', 'accdesc', 'investigator', 'accCPC','location','cdeptid','depdesc'];
  dataSource1= new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);


  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

   ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource1.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
}

export interface Element {
  accno: number;
  accdesc: string;
  investigator: string;
  accCPC: string;
  location:string;
  cdeptid: number;
  depdesc: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {accno: 5400343, accdesc: 'ASTRALIS LTD', investigator:'Kruger, James G.', accCPC: 'OR',location:'ON',cdeptid: 110350,depdesc: 'Kruger Laboratory'},

  {accno: 5400344, accdesc: 'ASTRALIS LTD', investigator:'Gelbard, Alyssa.', accCPC: 'OR',location:'ON',cdeptid: 110350,depdesc: 'Kruger Laboratory'}

];
```

### account.component.html

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" style="width:100%"> WELCOME </mat-toolbar><br/>

<h3>Department</h3><br/>

            <mat-form-field>
                      <mat-select style="min-width: 200px;" placeholder="Type to search" [(value)]="dept">
                      <input class="input1" matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="filtertext">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let dep of departments  | filter:filtertext  " [value]="dep.department" >
                          {{ dep.department }}
                        </mat-option>
                      </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>


<!-- Table starts here -->

<mat-card>
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource1">

    <!-- Account No. Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="accno">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Account No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.accno}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Account Description Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="accdesc">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Account Description </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.accdesc}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Investigator Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="investigator">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Investigator </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.investigator}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Account CPC Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="accCPC">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Account CPC </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.accCPC}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

     <!-- Location Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="location">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Location </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.location}}</mat-cell>
       </ng-container>


     <!-- Client Dept ID Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="cdeptid">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ClientDeptID </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.cdeptid}}</mat-cell>
       </ng-container>


    <!-- Dept Description Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="depdesc">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Dept Description  </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.depdesc}}</mat-cell>
       </ng-container>


    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns1" ></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns1;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
                 [pageSize]="10"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
</mat-card>
```

I want to know how can i change my table code snippet in my **accountcomponent.ts** file and subscribe the data from the service.

can anybody please guide me through this.....?

Comment: What do you mean by 'subscribe the data from the service'?

Comment: after mapping the data in the service from the requested URL ,we need to subscribe the data in the required component ...!

Comment: But you already do in your code, Does this not work? What is actually the issue here?

Comment: i just subscribed to my department drop down ... but in my table i am using the data specified manually in my accountcomponent.ts file...

Comment: i want to replace that manually edited data to subscribe from my service.how can i implement that?

Comment: you should assign  that manually edited data to variables and then in subscribe method assign the response data to those variable and then they will change automatically in DOM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this :

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.accdetailservice.accountdetails()
  .subscribe(data => {
     this.departments = data;
     // Add this row
     this.dataSource1.data = data;
  });
}
```

Just so you know since Angular 4.3 i think, you should use HttpClient instead of Http

Comment: I am accessing account details from a backend service and just accessing department values in my department dropdown ....can you please tell me how can i access distinct data in my dropdown as my dropdown contains duplicates....?

Comment: I have the same issue but the json keys from my API are different from the datasource keys. How to set the data to table manually?

Comment: This works fine, if you change the page size of the table, but it won;t work if you click next page or last page.