# How to sum up the values entered in the mat-table column using mat-input in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to sum up the values entered in the `mat-table` column using an input.

I have created a table with 3 columns: `Account Id`, `Account Description` and `Value`. I have also created a JSON file in the assets folder with the values for `acc_id` and `acc_desc` .

I then access these values in my table for the respective columns.

I have also created a `Value` column for which i have assigned input field.

Next to the table i took a simple grid with two tiles where i want to take the sum of all the values entered in the `Value` column.

`account.component.html`

```html
<!-- Table starts here -->

<mat-card>
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource1">

    <!-- Account No. Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="acc_id">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Account ID. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.acc_id}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Account Description Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="acc_des">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Account Description </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.acc_des }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

        <!-- Value Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><input matInput value=0> </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>


    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns1" ></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns1;" > </mat-row>

  </mat-table>

   <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="20:1">

  <mat-grid-tile> Total</mat-grid-tile>

 <mat-grid-tile> {{dataSource1.data.reduce((summ, v) => summ += v.value, 0)}} </mat-grid-tile>



</mat-grid-list>

</div>
</mat-card>
```

`account.component.ts`

```ts
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup,FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import { AccountdetailService } from '../accountdetail.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  templateUrl: './account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account.component.scss']
   })


export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {

constructor( private accdetailservice: AccountdetailService ) { }


  /* Table Starts here
  ---------------------- */

 displayedColumns1 = ['acc_id', 'acc_des', 'value'];
 dataSource1= new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);


ngOnInit(){
  this.accdetailservice.accountdetails()
  .subscribe(data =>
     this.dataSource1.data = data;
  ); }
 }

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [];
```

`accountdetails.service.ts`

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class AccountdetailService {

  constructor(private http:Http ) { }

  accountdetails()
  {
    return this.http.get('/assets/accountdetails.json')
    .map(result => result.json());
  }}
```

`accountdetails.json`

```json
[
    {
        "acc_id": 1001,
        "acc_des": "aaa"

    },

    {
        "acc_id": 1002,
        "acc_des": "aaa"

    }
]
```

`app.module.ts`

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

import { AppMaterialModule } from './app-material.module';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AccountComponent } from './account/account.component';

import { AccountdetailService } from './accountdetail.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AccountComponent    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppMaterialModule,
    FormsModule ,
    HttpModule   
  ],
  entryComponents:[ ],

  providers: [ AccountdetailService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How can i sum up my values and display the sum in the grid tile?
I am getting the below error...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

In component

```
 ngOnInit(){
  this.accdetailservice.accountdetails()
  .subscribe(data =>
  this.dataSource1.data= data.map(obj => ({...obj, value: 0}))
  );
 }


calculation(){ 
return dataSource1.data.reduce((summ, v) => summ += parseInt(v.value), 0) 
}
```

in Html

```
<mat-grid-tile> Total: {{calculation()}}</mat-grid-tile>
```

also change `<input matInput value=0>` to `<input matInput value="element.value"/>`

### Edit:

as per the chat discussion you need to use value parameter as a dynamic parameter to calculate

So try this below way

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="value">
   <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value </mat-header-cell>
   <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
     <ng-container>
       <input  [(ngModel)]="element.value">
     </ng-container>
   </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: but in the value column ,i am not fetching the data from my json file ,,,instead i have taken an input and I am manually entering the values in the value column in my UI

Comment: @Heena Now are you facing that issue?

Comment: are you busy sir ...?

Comment: @Heena Yup.  But I am thinking how can you get the values in outside of the table?

Comment: Please try this `value="element.value"` instead of  `value = 0`  in your input field.

Comment: and in my .ts ... datasource also needs to replaced na..?

Comment: add 'change' event handler to inputs in which call ChangeDetectionRef detectChanges()

Comment: sorry... i didn't get this..!

Comment: @tano Don't need that. If any `mat-cell` value is changing then automatically the `mat-tail` will triggered. So that function would be trigger  :)

Comment: I see. I don't use that. This case there must be with the value field. Maybe it it is undefined in the object.  should be convert it after initialized.  `code` dataSource1.data.forEach(d => d.value = 0)

Comment: @tano That's why I have dynamically created an object named as `value` in the input filed  `[(ngModel)]="element.value"`. Please refer  my answer. Also  I have discussed with the OP  in  chat and resolved with her expectation.

Comment: @ramesh rajendra... can you please open our discussion .. i have sent you a message

Comment: @Heena OOPS. That was a long chat. So I have deleted that.

Comment: i am getting the result but i am also getting the following error in my terminla

Comment: i added that screen shot in my question .. please take a look

Comment: Could you please add that value as an object in your json?

Comment: but i dont wanna add it there..
i just wan to access the values for only two columns from my json file

Comment: @Heena  Okay no problem .  Please change `element.value` to `element["value"]` . It should work

Comment: i am getting same html code snippet in my input container in the UI

Comment: @Heena Update my answer as well. Please go and check `ngOnInit()`

Comment: its giving me error now...ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: ELEMENT_DATA is not defined

Comment: why are we again mapping here in .ts file...? we have already mapped in service class...!

Comment: @Heena Do you have value property in the `Element` class?

Comment: check out this question...if anything to edit please help...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49044826/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-element

Answer (score 4):

Try a  reducer:

```
<mat-grid-tile> Total: {{dataSource1.data.reduce((summ, v) => summ += v.value, 0)}}</mat-grid-tile>
```

Comment: i tried using the above code ... but its giving me the following error which i have posted a screen shot in my question

Comment: this is the error ....compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 30 in [ Total: {{dataSource1.data.reduce((summ, v) => summ += v.value, 0)}}] in ng:///AppModule/AccountComponent.html@33:17 ("
   <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="20:1">

  <mat-grid-tile>[ERROR ->] Total: {{dataSource1.data.reduce((summ, v) => summ += v.value, 0)}}</mat-grid-tile>

</mat-grid-li"): ng:///AppModule/AccountComponent.html@33:17
Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 35