# How do I filter an angular material table using ngrx?

Tags: angular, filter, angular-material, ngrx

I'm using angular 4 + angular material + ngrx with actions/effects/reducers.  I have an array in my store of customer data (name, address, US state).

In my component, I have a mat-table of all the customers and a drop-down of 50 states.  I'm using the async pipe in my component HTML and the full list of customers displays perfectly.

Now, when the user selects a state I want to filter the table and display only customers in that state without going back to the server since I already have all the customers in the store.

Whats the best practice design pattern for this?  Can I filter the table in the component without affecting the store?  Is this even possible?

Or do I need to dispatch an action and do the filter in a reducer?  If this is the best approach I imagine I will have to keep 2 arrays in the store: One that holds ALL customers, and one that will be the filtered array which is the one I would bind to the component.  This seems cleaner and more in-line with the pattern but requires duplicating a potentially large set of customer data.

Some sample code (or link) of the recommended approach or similar solution is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: could you share your source?

Comment: if you are using Material table there is no need to maintain two arrays, material does it for you. You can just provide filter to datasource. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: see this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769015/filter-in-dropdown-matselect-not-working-with-data-from-http-get-request

Answer (score 1):

On select of dropdown call `applyFilter` function in HTML, define `applyFilter` in `component` as:

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
}
```

in `ngOnInit()` add the predicate to customize your filter as:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getCustomers().subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
    });

    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter): boolean {
      return data.state.toLowerCase() == filter;
    };
}
```

*HTML*

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
```

You can also find the example [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to store all customers in ngrx store, especially that data like customers, orders, products, etc. can grow rapidly so it can result in loading huge amounts of data in the feature.

I prefer using direct http services in a grid component especially when there are implemented thinks like filtering/sorting/pagination by server-side (eg. it's easier to combine  `Kendo Grid` with OData directly by http services then by store).

If you have to share data from the grid, your component can dispatch action like `GridDataLoaded({ items: items})` and then others can consume date by selectors.